# How to force the WPF TreeView embedded in an Expander to Re-Arrange the size?

Tags: wpf, treeview, expander

I have 3 expander in the Grid.Column which should share the available space (height). Some expander should get all space they need, some other should "share" the space when open. So I created a very simple StackablePanel with an AttachedProperty "ChildShareHeight". So far so good and my Panel is assigning the proper space for each expander. Unfortunately the Expander.Content is not reacting as expected. When the ExpanderContent block is smaller than the TreeView the internal ScrollViewer from the TreeView control is not appearing and I don't find a way how to limit the TreeView size to the size of the Expander.Content element (to activate the ScrollViewer) or how to force an layout update for the Expander.Content element.

These 2 pictures illustrates my problem:
[1] Enough space - no sharing (https://ibb.co/FBGFxNW)
[2] Not enough space - active sharing (https://ibb.co/K2s4nB9).
To verify the Layout process I located an "transparent" Panel in the Expander.Content element to track the Measure and Arrange functions. Each Expander is triggered properly for Measure and Arrange, but the Expander.Content isn't updated.

I was also looking for some other solutions like Binding the TreeView MaxHeight property to some external elements, but I didn't found any working solution yet.
Putting the whole group of Expander's into an ScrollViewer isn't an option to me.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Below the XAML of my example.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <uic:StackablePanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
        <Expander Header="Expander 1" IsExpanded="False" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Blue" uic:StackablePanel.ChildShareHeight="False">
            <Expander.Content>
                <uic:HeightLimitPanel >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" uic:HeightLimitPanel.ExpanderName="Expander 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Test 10"/>
                       ...
                    </StackPanel>
                </uic:HeightLimitPanel>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="Expander 2" IsExpanded="False" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Red" uic:StackablePanel.ChildShareHeight="True">
            <Expander.Content>
                <uic:HeightLimitPanel >
                    <TreeView uic:HeightLimitPanel.ExpanderName="Expander 2">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Test 2" IsExpanded="True">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Text 2.10"/>
                            ...
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Text 2.18"/>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>
                </uic:HeightLimitPanel>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="Expander 3" IsExpanded="False" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" uic:StackablePanel.ChildShareHeight="True" >
            <Expander.Content>
                <uic:HeightLimitPanel>
                    <TreeView uic:HeightLimitPanel.ExpanderName="Expander 3">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Test 3" IsExpanded="True">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Text 3.10"/>
                             ...

                            <TreeViewItem Header="Text 3.21"/>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>
                </uic:HeightLimitPanel>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
    </uic:StackablePanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the MaterialDesign for WPF library with own Style for Expander control. I found in the Style an StackPanel surrounding the ContentPresenter. This was the problem, why the TreeView don't used the embedded ScrollViewer. I created own Style without the StackPanel and the problem is fixed.